# MySQL help, updating fields based on a calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I've been trying to work out this particular problem and though I can easily think of a sort of brute force PHP + MySQL solution, I want some guidance on solving this particular problem without iterating through fields with PHP.

So.. with that, here's the problem.
I want to precalculate each room's size relative to all other rooms with a single query (or 3), such that rooms that are bigger than 66% of all other rooms can have a category filled in as Large, while rooms within a 33%-66% range are given Medium and the rest are considered Small.

I have a general idea of how to complete this, but I'm hoping that someone more adept as SQL queries could at least point me in the right direction.

The hardest part for me comes with being able to simultaneously update every field that fits the criteria of falling within a certain range :(.

Here's an example of the table

```
Rooms
    ID | Length | Width | Relative Size [Expected Values]
    ------------------------------------
    1  | 15     | 12    | Large
    2  | 15     | 12    | Large
    3  | 10     | 10    | Medium
    4  | 10     | 10    | Medium
    5  | 8      | 9     | Small
    6  | 8      | 8     | Small
    7  | 8      | 7     | Small
    8  | 10     | 9     | Medium
```

I'd be perfectly happy with a resources or clues that can assist me with this, but I've been going in circles.

Thanks for any attempts at helping me out.

Edit: I ended up going with a standard deviation approach, since it makes a lot more sense in this case, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I wouldn't categorise rooms based on how many rooms are larger or smaller than the given one, but rather based on their size relative to maximum and minimum sizes found. If there were 2 rooms 15×10, 12 rooms 10×9, and 3 rooms 8×8, I would end up with wrong categories assigned, if I assigned them using your method.

Comment: So true, the method was proposed to me by my boss, and I was definitely more concerned with getting his method to work as opposed to thinking out the actual faulty implications...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt think of a way to do it in 1 query but here is my attempt to do it in 3, assuming size is Null before populating

```
Update table set size = 'Large' where ID in (select TOP 33 PERCENT ID from table order by length*width Desc)

Update table set size = 'Small' where ID in (select TOP 33 PERCENT ID from table order by length*width Asc)

Update table set size = 'Medium' where size = null
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot, I'm going to work on actually converting it to MySQL notation.. which may take me a little bit of time because I'm really new to subqueries, but if no one else beats me to it I'll try to update your answer with a MySQL solution (Yours only works in regular SQL).